# Where can I find org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon class?

Tags: java, maven

I am studying how maven download dependency, I use `mvn clean compile` and use IDEA debug feature to trace code.

break point is `org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon` L126

here is the stack after press F7

```
fillInputData:1094, AbstractHttpClientWagon (org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared)
getInputStream:126, StreamWagon (org.apache.maven.wagon)
getIfNewer:88, StreamWagon (org.apache.maven.wagon)
get:61, StreamWagon (org.apache.maven.wagon)
...
```

And I can't find the `org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon` class anywhere.

here is my current dependency.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-http-shared</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I only find a same name `org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon` class from `wagon-http-shared`, but the package name is different.

**EDIT**:
I use maven 3.6.1 IDEA 2019.3.3 bundled version

Comment: You can search maven central repository by fully-qualified class name: https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon

Comment: @Eng.Fouad it shows `wagon-http` has the class, but it doesn't, there is only one class(HttpWagon) in the dependency

Comment: Why vote to close this question? I'm not seeking any recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you are searching for is included in maven's installation directory.

Full path is

`MAVEN_INSTALLATION_DIR/lib/wagon-http-$VERSION-shaded.jar`

Note that `$VERSION` depends on Maven's version you have installed.

**Edit:** Classes source code can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/blob/master/wagon-providers/wagon-http-shared/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wagon/shared/http/AbstractHttpClientWagon.java). You have stated in comments that source's and jar's class package differs. That's partially true, but this is explained by checking artifacts [wagon-providers artifact's pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/blob/505455fceb3e5e4efcd44958fc1f8acd5f9539e5/wagon-providers/wagon-http/pom.xml).

Especially you should check configuration of [Maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

[Here](https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/blob/505455fceb3e5e4efcd44958fc1f8acd5f9539e5/wagon-providers/wagon-http/pom.xml#L128) artifact `wagon-http-shared` is included in the build process and [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/blob/505455fceb3e5e4efcd44958fc1f8acd5f9539e5/wagon-providers/wagon-http/pom.xml#L150) its package in the produced jar is changed.

Comment: the package name is different

Comment: What's the jar version that comes with your installed maven version?

Comment: I am using maven 3.6.1 IDEA 2019.3.3 bundled version, and the lib version is wagon-http-3.3.2-shaded.jar

Comment: Why they do such things....it make whole IDEA strong debug feature broken :(

Comment: @user1686407 I added some extra info. I understand that the whole thing can be confusing but normally provided jars are kind of stable and you should not debug them. You should focus on debugging your code.